# How to integrate emotion icons in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, social-networking

what is the best way to handle emotion icons in angularJS? Have looked at angular-emoji-filter(https://github.com/globaldev/angular-emoji-filter), but that seems to have issues coz angular no longer supports ng-bind-html-unsafe.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Check out this directive and filters: https://github.com/madhur/angular-emoji-popup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-bind-html with the ngSanitize module.

Official documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Download it here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular-sanitize.js

Just replace the "x.x.x" with your current AngularJS version number, e.g. 1.2.16